# preg_match_all to return push empty data to resulting array when no match found

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

im trying to use preg_match_all  on the following data

```
$data = "    .........data
    <p class='need'>
    ...........data
    </p>
    <p class='need'>
    ...........data
    </p>
    <p class='need'></p>

    <p class='need'>
    ...........data
    </p>
    <p class='need'></p>
";

preg_match_all("/.*?<p class=\"need\">(.*?)<\/p>/si",$data, $tmp);
```

the above returns all results in which data exists but i want a empty data to be included in the $tmp so that instead of getting 3 results , i get all the 5 but with no data when nothing is found...

any help is appreciated guys :)

Comment: Simple solution: stop using regexes on HTML. Use DOM instead. Then it's a simple matter of some xpath: `$found = $xpath->query("//p[@class='need']");`

Comment: I agree with Marc B, but I don't see why you have a problem, because $tmp[1] contains an array with NULL values where no data was found. So given the fact that keys exists for each one, you can loop through the array and test for NULL values. In other words, you ARE getting 5 results. 2 of them are just empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will definitely return 5 matches if regex is user correctly.

Problem is in this regex:

```
"/.*?<p class=\"need\">(.*?)<\/p>/si"
```

**If you look closely you are trying to match class `"need"` with double quotes whereas in your HTML code you're using that class wrapped in single quotes like this: `'need'`**

This is your corrected regex that will return 5 matches including 2 empty ones.

```
preg_match_all("/<p class='need'>(.*?)<\/p>/si", $data, $tmp);
```

**PS:** That is precisely the reason you should avoid parsing HTML using regex and consider using DOM parser.